# Element rotated 180 degrees ends up behind other elements

Tags: css, css-transforms

I noticed an unusual behavior when `transform-style: preserve-3d` is set and an element is rotated 180 degrees. It seems this causes the rotated element to go behind others, as if it has `z-index` set to a lower value.

Here's a sample:

```css
.parent {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.card.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.card.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card red"></div>
  <div class="card blue rotated"></div>
</div>
```

When using Chrome, the (rotated) blue card is on top in HTML, but the red card is visible instead. Giving a `z-index` to the blue card also seems to have no effect.

I couldn't find it documented anywhere - is this a glitch or expected behavior? Is there a way to ensure the blue card is shown instead (while keeping `transform-style: preserve-3d`)?

**Edit:** it seems this behavior is not present in Firefox. However, it's unclear if this is an issue with Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform-style:preserve-3d` means *"the children of the element should be positioned in the (same) 3D-space"*. Which means if you apply 3d transformations to them they will be rendered accordingly.

Now, both your elements are at the same exact `z-index` value. Which is, by default, `auto`, which corresponds to `0`.
But if you rotate the element by `180deg` on Y or X axis, it will basically flip. Which means it will be at the other end of the same `z-index` value (because you set `transform-style:preserve-3d`). Which means it will be at the opposite end of the stack (from it's normal position - which is on top of its preceding siblings).

So you either give it specifically a bigger `z-index` or you switch their positions.

To understand more of this behavior play with the `rotateY`. You will notice at other values only half the element is visible, and that's the half that's closer to you, considering the rotation angle in 3d space.

At `90` and `270` degrees it will be invisible as it is perpendicular (and has no width) and at `180` it is *"completely"* rotated in 3d space, which means it's behind the other element that's at the same z-index value and (technically) "behind" it.

Another "fix" is to remove `preserve-3d` from the parent, (or move it to the child, as I.Johnson suggested), so the 2 elements are rendered each in its own space, and each representation of that space would be stacked according to their respective elements position in the stacking context.

Comment: While this makes a lot of sense, it doesn't seem to be true. If I understand you correctly, this implies that, if I give the blue card an negative `z-index`, it will be shown behind the red card by default, but will come up on top when flipped, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: If you give them different `z-index` values, they ***no are no longer at the same value*** and you're hard-coding their rendering order, regardless of `transform`. Besides, if you give an element a negative `z-index`, you are sending it behind it's relative parent.

Comment: Ah, I see, so this is like a separate "layer" inside the same `z-index`? I think that makes sense.

Comment: When they are at the same `z-index` they are rendered "together". Flipping one of them will send it at the reverse of the stack at that `z-index` level. Flipping it twice (on both axes) will flip it twice, reverting it to it's normal stacking position.

Comment: Does this mean that Firefox is actually not rendering correctly i.e. it's a bug in Gecko?

Comment: I'd say so. Documentation on stacking contexts [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html).

Comment: In all honesty, I didn't know you need `transform-style:preserve-3d` on the parent to get this behavior. I would have expected it to be default behavior between siblings anyway. (Because it makes sense geometrically). But, all things considered, it makes a more sense to have to specifically say: these children should be rendered together (by setting `transform-style` on parent) from an implementation point of view, in the sense that - having `z-index` order change on you for now apparent reason would be far more confusing.

Comment: My understanding is that `transform-style: flat` (the default) means "each element is in a separate 3D space". This means that the behavior you describe still holds even without `transform-style: preserve-3d`, but the elements are then rendered independently and stacked on top of each other after.

Comment: @fstanis, indeed. My above comment could be read as: *"I'd have expected `preserve-3d` to be default value of `transform-style`"* but from a development point of view it makes more sense it's `flat` and your question sort of underlines why that is the case. Good question!

Comment: Ah, right, it confused me as well when I learned [the behavior exhibited by] `preserve-3d` isn't the default. My only guess as to why is legacy reasons (ugh).

Answer (score 1):

When using the transform-style property it must be used together with the transform property.

Adding the `transform-style: preserve-3d;` property to the .rotated class displays the blue card

```
.rotated {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/IanJohnson/pen/jXGVVo?editors=1100

Comment: The w3schools.com article you linked to specifically says that `transform-style` is applied to **child elements** - in other words, your example works because that property has no effect, i.e. the 3D is not preserved. It's the same effect as just removing it all together.

Comment: If there is one thing I would amend at your answer would be it uses a w3schools link. w3schools is a private enterprise trying to capitalize on deceivingly naming themselves so that people would associate them with W3C. It's advisable to use either W3C links (to the documentation itself) or MDN links, which is an open source joint effort of Mozilla, Microsoft, Google and many others, including individual volunteer developers and who, unlike w3schools, are backed and supported by W3C. +1 from me nonetheless. Welcome to [so].

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu That is a great point I have never considered that. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think this is because the back of a DIV isn't necessarily the same color as the front.  So rotating on the Y axis you're seeing the back/invisible/transparent side of the DIV.  If you rotate on the Z axis you have the same face of the DIV visible.</strike>

Update: @fstanis pointed out that my transparent backing was incorrect.  So if the Z vs. Y axis does still work as expected, then I don't actually 100% know why :)

```css
.parent {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.card.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.card.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotateZ(175deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card red"></div>
  <div class="card blue rotated"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is, if you simply remove the red card, the rotated blue card stays blue, so the other side is definitely not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

because both cards has the same z-index
if you change your HTML to:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card red"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card blue rotated"></div>
</div>
```

it will render the blue one

Comment: I think this actually puts them in separate 3D spaces, effectively negating `transform-style: preserve-3d`.